# Add and save text description for an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I want create a page where there are several images along with a button.
When you click on a particular button, will appear a textarea where you can add description about the image.
Script Example:

- I clicked on image A button
- I wrote a description of the image A
- now, i clicked on image B button.
- description of the image B will display (description of the image A not appear)
- Again, i clicked on image A button, description of the image A will display
  Of course, there can be several pictures, you can add images.

I'm a new student at html, jquery, etc, and i really do not know how to begin with this task.
I appreciate you help.

I have started with the following code:

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="index.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            body {
                background-color: #E0EBEB;
            }

            h1 {
                color: orange;
                text-align: center;
            }
            input[type="text"] {
                height: 30px;
                width: 400px;
                padding: 10px;
                margin-right: 10px;
                 margin-bottom: 20px;
                font-size: 15px;
                border-radius: 5px;
            }  
            input[type="submit"]{
                height: 30px;
                font-size: 15px;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h1><b>Gallery</b></h1>
            <input type="text"  id="new-text" placeholder="enter URL">
            <input type="submit" id="add" value="Add"><br/>
            <textarea class="bescription"></textarea>
            <ul id="imagelist">
               <li><input type="image" class="show" src="http://oferflowerstelaviv.files.wordpress.com/2011/05/0131.jpg" alt="Roses" width="150" height="150"></li>               
            </ul>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $("#add").on('click', addListItem);
    $(document).on('click', '.show', showDescription);
});

function addListItem() {
    if ($("#new-text").val() !== '') {
        var text = $("#new-text").val();
        $('#imagelist').append('<li><input type="image" src="' + text + '" width="150" height="150"></li>');
        $("#new-text").val('');
    }
}

function showDescription(){
    $('#bescription').val('write bescription');
}
```

Comment: Nice set of requirements. What did you try?

Comment: You can start by building it :) Do the HTML and CSS first, then try adding the functionality later.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to catch the textarea with `$('#bescription')` - but `bescription` (supposed to be description, right?) is a **class** and the `#` selector is for an ID. Either change the jQuery to `$('.bescription')` or change the class to an id in the HTML `<textarea id="bescription"></textarea>`